# Can't find org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer

Tags: zk

I use Eclipse with ZK plugin. Project also was created using zk plugin. 
Trying to get started with bindings stucked with error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"... I see that the library with this class is in the build path and web app libraries. I am going through tutorial http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/MVVM/Data%20Binding/BindComposer

Comment: 'org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer' is in zkbind.jar Can you confirm it is actually on the application class path? It might be there on the eclipse build path and even within Web app libraries but is it being deployed to the server correctly? From the ClassNotFoundException it seems not.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this type of problem try [ZK Studio](http://www.zkoss.org/download/zkstudio)

Rather than manually adding jar file..Now You can create a ZK Project Jar automatically added to the project lib folder.